# How to async import all Vue3 components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to make the components work. I want to have component names in the array, then import components as async and then somehow put the variable into app.component. I've been trying for about 6 hours here and I can't figure it out. I don't want to have 50x **import** and 50x **app.component** for each component and it doesn't want to work for me I'm probably missing something obvious. Unfortunately, I'm not that good at JS.

**main.js**

```
import { createApp, defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

var subComponents = new Array([
  "test", 
  "test2"
]);  

subComponents.forEach(subComponent => {
  subComponent = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
    import(`@/components/sub/${subComponent}.vue`)       
  )
});

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);
app.component(subComponent, subComponents);
app.mount("#app");
```

**It reports these problems**

> Failed to resolve component: test

> Failed to resolve component: test2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is to register each component individually inside the loop like this:

**subComponents.js:**

```
const subComponents = ['test', 'test2'];

export { subComponents }
```

**main.js:**

```
import { createApp, defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import { subComponents } from './subComponents';

const app = createApp(App);

subComponents.forEach(subComponent => {
    const component = defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`@/components/sub/${subComponent}.vue`));

    app.component(subComponent, component);
});

app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

At the moment you're passing a non-existent `subComponent` variable as the first argument to a single instance of `app.component` and the array as the second argument.

`app.component` should be used for a single component, the first argument being the components' name, the second being the component itself.

So, if you loop through your array of names and import each component using that name, then register a component using the name and imported component, they'll be available throughout your app.

Comment: What should I do if I want to put this array into another file and import it here? I tried and it doesn't work if it's in another file.

Comment: Should work as you'd expect, edited my answer to include this